# Use a variable as a field specifier for a projection inside a find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I want use a variable in Key inside a `find()` in mongodb. I want to do a request similar to `select value from table;`.

I tried this: `value = '{ "' + axey.options[i].value + '" : 1, "_id" : 0 }';`

and I do my request in this way : `Validation.find({}, value ).fetch();`

Someone know how can I use my value like a "Key" and not like a value ?

Comment: Post your SQL query and we might be able to show that in noSQL way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to construct the projection document. You also need to include the [field specifier](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers) in your projection document. For example:

```
var projection = { "fields": { "_id": 0 } };
projection["fields"][axey.options[0].value] = 1;
Validation.find({}, projection ).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly though if you want to know if certain key in your documents exists as you mentioned select key in table than you can do by this.

```
Collection.find("keyName": {$exists:true}).fetch();
```